# Hibernate @Where annotation not working with inheritance

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, where-clause

I am using Hibernate 5.1.2

I have run into an unexpected problem that I can't seem to work around. Here's the summary of my data model:
[image]

`dfip_project_version` is my superclass table, and `dfip_appln_proj_version` is my subclass table. `dfip_application` contains a list of `dfip_appln_proj_version`s.

I have mapped this as follows:

```
@Table(name = "DFIP_PROJECT_VERSION")
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class AbstractProjectVersion {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "PROJECT_VERSION_OID")
    Long oid;

    @Column(name = "PROJ_VSN_EFF_FROM_DTM")
    Timestamp effFromDtm;

    @Column(name = "PROJ_VSN_EFF_TO_DTM")
    Timestamp effToDtm;

    @Column(name = "PROJECT_VERSION_TYPE")
    @Type(type = "project_version_type")
    ProjectVersionType projectVersionType;
}


@Table(name = "DFIP_APPLN_PROJ_VERSION")
@Entity
class ApplicationProjectVersion extends AbstractProjectVersion {

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "APPLICATION_OID", nullable = false)
    Application application;

    public ApplicationProjectVersion() {
        projectVersionType = ProjectVersionType.APPLICATION;
    }
}

@Table(name = "DFIP_APPLICATION")
@Entity
class Application {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "APPLICATION_OID")
    Long oid;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="application", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    @Where(clause = "PROJ_VSN_EFF_TO_DTM is null")
    List<ApplicationProjectVersion> applicationVersions = [];
}
```

I am using the `@Where` annotation so that only the current `ApplicationProjectVersion` is retrieved with the `Application`.

The problem with this is that Hibernate assumes that the column I am referencing is in the `dfip_appl_proj_version` table, when it's actually on the super-class table (`dfip_project_version`).

Here's what I tried so far to work around this limitation:

**Attempt 1**

I tried putting the `@Where` annotation onto the `AbstractProjectVersion` super-class, like so:

```
@Table(name = "DFIP_PROJECT_VERSION")
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Where(clause = "PROJ_VSN_EFF_TO_DTM is null")
public abstract class AbstractProjectVersion {
    ...etc...
}
```

This did nothing, as the WHERE clause does not seem to be noticed when retrieving the `Application`.

---

**Attempt 2**

I made the `applicationVersions` list on `Application` LAZY, and tried to map `latestVersion` manually like this:

```
@Table(name = "DFIP_APPLICATION")
@Entity
class Application {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "APPLICATION_OID")
    Long oid;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="application", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    List<ApplicationProjectVersion> applicationVersions = [];

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumnsOrFormulas([
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(value = "(APPLICATION_OID)", referencedColumnName="APPLICATION_OID")),
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(value = "(select apv.PROJECT_VERSION_OID from DFIP_PROJECT_VERSION pv, DFIP_APPLN_PROJ_VERSION apv where apv.PROJECT_VERSION_OID = pv.PROJECT_VERSION_OID and apv.APPLICATION_OID = APPLICATION_OID and pv.PROJ_VSN_EFF_TO_DTM is null)", referencedColumnName="PROJECT_VERSION_OID")),
    ])
    ApplicationProjectVersion latestVersion;
}
```

This caused Hibernate to generate the following SQL (snippet):

```
from DFIP_APPLICATION this_ 
left outer join DFIP_APPLN_PROJ_VERSION applicatio2_ 
    on (this_.APPLICATION_OID)=applicatio2_.APPLICATION_OID and 
       (select apv.PROJECT_VERSION_OID from DFIP_PROJECT_VERSION pv, DFIP_APPLN_PROJ_VERSION apv 
        where apv.PROJECT_VERSION_OID = pv.PROJECT_VERSION_OID and apv.APPLICATION_OID = this_.APPLICATION_OID 
        and pv.PROJ_VSN_EFF_TO_DTM is null)=applicatio2_.PROJECT_VERSION_OID
```

which resulted in `ORA-01799: a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery`.

If I can't specify a sub-query in my join formula, then I cannot join to the super-class manually...

---

**Attempt 3**

I noticed that usage of `@JoinFormula` makes Hibernate notice my `@Where` annotation on the super-class. So I tried the following:

```
@Table(name = "DFIP_PROJECT_VERSION")
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Where(clause = "PROJ_VSN_EFF_TO_DTM is null")
public abstract class AbstractProjectVersion {
    ...etc...
}

@Table(name = "DFIP_APPLICATION")
@Entity
class Application {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "APPLICATION_OID")
    Long oid;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="application", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    List<ApplicationProjectVersion> applicationVersions = [];

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinFormula(value = "(APPLICATION_OID)", referencedColumnName="APPLICATION_OID")
    ApplicationProjectVersion latestVersion;
}
```

This generated the following SQL (snippet):

```
from DFIP_APPLICATION this_ 
left outer join DFIP_APPLN_PROJ_VERSION applicatio2_ 
    on (this_.APPLICATION_OID)=applicatio2_.APPLICATION_OID and ( applicatio2_1_.PROJ_VSN_EFF_TO_DTM is null) 
left outer join DFIP_PROJECT_VERSION applicatio2_1_ on applicatio2_.PROJECT_VERSION_OID=applicatio2_1_.PROJECT_VERSION_OID
```

This is almost correct! Unfortunately it is not valid SQL, since `applicatio2_1_` is used before it is declared on the next line :(.

---

Now I am out of ideas, so any help would be appreciated. Is there a way to  specify a WHERE clause that will bring in only the current ProjectVersion, without getting rid of my inheritance structure?

[Related Hibernate issue ticket](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12016)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a solution to this problem. I must admit, it ended up being a little more cumbersome than what I hoped for, but it does work quite well. I waited a couple of months before posting, to make sure that there are no issues and so far, I have not experienced any problems.

My entities are still mapped exactly as described in the question, but instead of using the problematic `@Where` annotation, I had to use `@Filter` annotation instead:

```
public class Application {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="application", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cascade([SAVE_UPDATE, DELETE, MERGE])
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)

    // Normally we'd just use the @Where(clause = "PROJ_VSN_EFF_TO_DTM is null"), but that doesn't work with collections of
    // entities that use inheritance, as we have here.
    //
    // Hibernate thinks that PROJ_VSN_EFF_TO_DTM is a column on DFIP_APPLN_PROJ_VERSION table, but it is actually on the "superclass"
    // table (DFIP_PROJECT_VERSION). 
    //
    // B/c of this, we have to do the same thing with a Filter, which is defined on AbstractProjectVersion.
    // NOTE: This filter must be explicitly enabled, which is currently achieved by HibernateForceFiltersAspect 
    //
    @Filter(name="currentProjectVersionOnly", 
        condition = "{pvAlias}.PROJ_VSN_EFF_TO_DTM is null", 
        deduceAliasInjectionPoints=false, 
        aliases=[ @SqlFragmentAlias(alias = "pvAlias", table = "DFIP_PROJECT_VERSION") ]
    )
    List<ApplicationProjectVersion> projectVersions = [];

}
```

Since we are using a Filter, we must also define it:

```
// NOTE: This filter needs to be explicitly turned on with session.enableFilter("currentProjectVersionOnly");
// This is currently achieved with HibernateForceFiltersAspect
@FilterDef(name="currentProjectVersionOnly")

@Table(name = "DFIP_PROJECT_VERSION")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class AbstractProjectVersion  {

}
```

And of course, we must enable it, since Hibernate does not have a setting to automatically turn on all filters.

To do this I created a system-wide Aspect, whose job is to enable specified filters before every call to any DAO:

```
/**
 * Enables provided Hibernate filters every time a Hibernate session is openned.
 * 
 * Must be enabled and configured explicitly from Spring XML config (i.e. no auto-scan here)
 *
 * @author Val Blant
 */
@Aspect
public class HibernateForceFiltersAspect {

    List<String> filtersToEnable = [];

    @PostConstruct
    public void checkConfig() throws Exception {
        if ( filtersToEnable.isEmpty() ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Missing required property 'filtersToEnable'");
        }
    }

    /**
     * This advice gets executed before all method calls into DAOs that extend from <code>HibernateDao</code>
     * 
     * @param jp
     */
    @Before("@target(org.springframework.stereotype.Repository) && execution(* ca.gc.agr.common.dao.hibernate.HibernateDao+.*(..))")
    public void enableAllFilters(JoinPoint jp) {
        Session session = ((HibernateDao)jp?.getTarget())?.getSession();

        if ( session != null ) {
            filtersToEnable.each { session.enableFilter(it) } // Enable all specified Hibernate filters
        }
    }

}
```

And the corresponding Spring configuration:

```
<!-- This aspect is used to force-enable specified Hibernate filters for all method calls on DAOs that extend HibernateDao -->  
<bean class="ca.gc.agr.common.dao.hibernate.HibernateForceFiltersAspect">
    <property name="filtersToEnable">
        <list>
            <value>currentProjectVersionOnly</value>            <!-- Defined in AbstractProjectVersion -->
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And there you have it - polymorphic `@Where` clause :).

Answer (score 0):

since you are looking for @Where with inheritance, I assume you are trying to apply some SQL logic globally, maybe hibernate interceptor or SQL inspector would be a better fit for this type of requirement

Comment: Not sure what about my question suggested global SQL logic... The question is about an @Where clause on a collection of a specific entity that happens to use inheritance.